# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError in python?

Tags: python

I am using the openbabel module in Python 3.7.3, the code was operated well in pycharm IDE environment. But when I tried to execute the python script in terminal (windows), that is not worked and show ModuleNotFoundError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\com\PycharmProjects\base\docking\src\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openbabel import OBMol, OBConversion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openbabel'
```

I guess the problem was associated with sys.path. But the path of the openbabel module was saved in sys. path list

```
from openbabel import OBMol, OBConversion
import sys

sys.path = list(set(sys.path))

for i in sys.path:
    print(i)

obmol = OBMol()
obconversion = OBConversion()
obconversion.GetInAndOutFormats("pdb", "pdbqt")
```

sys.path

```
['C:\\Users\\com\\Miniconda3\\envs\\ground\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\com\\Miniconda3\\envs\\ground\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\com\\Miniconda3\\envs\\ground\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\python27\\include', 
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Users\\com\\Miniconda3\\envs\\ground\\python37.zip', 'C:/Users/com/PycharmProjects/base', 
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\\helpers\\third_party\\thriftpy', 'C:\\Users\\com\\Miniconda3\\envs\\ground', 'C:\\Users\\com\\PycharmProjects\\base']
```

openbabel.py path:

```
"C:\Users\com\Miniconda3\envs\ground\lib\site-packages"
```

I don't know the cause of this problem... I need to your help. thank you.

Comment: PyCharm uses venv (virtual environment). You have to either run the same venv in your terminal or install the package for the whole python (not inside the venv).

Comment: Thank you!! I solve the problem